# foursquare api venues search intent=match not working?

Tags: foursquare

I have been using foursquare api venues search with intent=match and it returned reasonable results a few months ago. Now, when I do the same search, results are empty.

E.g.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=51.4914147,-0.1608899%20&client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&v=20131016&intent=match&query=The%20Five%20Fields

returns an empty venues array, despite of the version parameter being the same as before. It does not return an error, just the empty array (with valid clientId and clientSecret).
It still works with intent=checkin, but the match seems like an obvious choice for me. Any ideas why it doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

`intent=match` is still working.

E.g.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=51.4914147,-0.1608899&client_id=(YOUR_CLIENT_ID)&client_secret=(YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET)&v=20131016&intent=match&query=John%20Sandoe%20Books

I don't know why, but it does not work “John Sandoe Books” only..

Comment: It works for some venues, but stopped working for many others. E.g. for the one in the question, it works with the default `intent=checkin`, see https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=51.4914147,-0.1608899%20&client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&v=20131016&query=The%20Five%20Fields, I cannot see a reason why that should not work with `intent=match`